# Rails - Validate unique month in year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, activerecord

Using Rails 6.

I have a model, `MonthlyConsumption`, which is a measure of a monthly energy consumption. It contains the following fields:

- `month` as an integer from 1-12; This is later converted into a month using some key-value pairs e.g `1: 'January'`
- `year`: an integer, e.g `2020`
- `amount`: an integer, the amount of power consumption in kW
- `city_id`: A reference to a `City` model

I want to validate that there is only 1 possible entry in one month of a given year, per city.

For example:

- `500kW in January 2020 in City X` & `600kW in January 2021 in City X` should both be valid
- `500kW in January 2020 in City X` & `600kW in January 2020 in City Y` should both be valid
- `500kW in January 2020 in City X` & `600kW in January 2020 in City X` should be invalid

What would be the best way of accomplishing this validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```rb
validates :month, uniqueness: { scope: [:city_id, :year] }
```